# React-Router params rewrites script and link tag urls

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use React-Router v2.5.2.

My routes look like this:

```
var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route path="challenges" component={ChallengeView} />
          <Route path="c/:id" component={ChallengeDetails} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Every component renders fine, as long as I do not write params into the path of the route.

E.g.:

```
<Route path="c" component={ChallengeDetails} />
```

Would render the component just fine.

But as soon as I request params inside the url the component does not render at all and my paths of the script and css tags are rewritten (console errors).

E.g.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/c/build/css/style.css 
GET http://localhost:3000/c/build/main.js
```

My javascript and styles are placed by Gulp inside the build folder (which is located besides the index.html). React-Router somehow adds the "c/"-Route to the URL, but only if the route contains a parameters. The associated componenent is not rendered at all (React-DevTools can't find any component).

Edit:
My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <script src="build/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I render parameter routes correctly?

Comment: How did you address your css/js file in the html page. you should use Absolute path when you what to address these files. 
When you use relative path, the browser calculates paths differently in pages in these urls: "http://localhost/c/1" and "http://localhost/c"
Could you provide a sample of your html page

Comment: I added my _old_ index.html for reference but @NimaShahri has the solution. I haven't used absolute paths. Adding a slash right in front of `build/` solves the problem. Thanks.